# How long do ring creations last?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

The objects created by a Green Lantern power ring- unless the ring bearer 'erases' (for lack of a better word) them- do they exist for a finite period of time?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the objects exist as long as the ring-bearer keeps willing them. If he breaks concentration, they vanish immediately.